# I have an unordered list of dynamically created input list, How can I use jquery to make sure a user can't give two inputs the same answer?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jquery... I'm working on an independent project/ game for learning, where a user can check 3 images out of a list of 10 images. Once a button is clicked those checked images are appended to a new unordered list.(That i'm currently working on) In this section the 3 images are displayed each with there own input field where I'm trying to allow a user to rate each image in the new list. I already have jquery that only allows a user to input a number 0-10. But I want to add some code to disable a user from giving two images the same value

This is my code to append the checked images...

```
$('#confirm').click(function(){
    //Make the rateSection Viewable
$('#checkedImageContainer').removeClass('hidden');
    //Disable the confirm . button from being clicked again
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
 ///For each input checked = true > append that image + an input type:number + label(Rate)
$("input[name='tool']").each(function () {
if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $('.checkedImageList').append('<li><img src="'+$(this).parent('li').find('img').attr('src') +'"><input class="rateInput" type="number"  min="0" max="10"/><label id="RateButton">Rate</label></li>');
    });
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('input').change(function() {
  if ($('input').not(this).map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
  }).get().indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0)
   $(this).val('');
  });
```

This question was a repost because I was impatient... 
So I can't take the credit for answering this myself lol... credit goes to

[image]